# Selecting nth-child elements in mobile email

Tags: mobile, html-email, css-selectors

I'm trying to have a backup for some issues we're seeing with our responsive emails that come from ad serving.  Occasionally, our ads come with a 3rd party script that pulls in a 1x1 tracking pixel.  We use a global rule for our images to resize... img{width:100%;height:auto;} and there's no way we can target this tracking pixel using a class or id.  I'm playing with the idea of using the nth-child selector to size the tracking pixel properly at least on mobile devices, as they can for the most part support that kind of CSS, although, I'm not writing it properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/pxdunn/jk8EC/

HTML:

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="ad-728">
    <font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#858585;font-size:10px;text-transform:uppercase;line-height:13px;display:block;" align="center">Advertisement</font>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" height="2" style="line-height:2px;font-size:2px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="http://oascentral.modernhealthcare.com/RealMedia/ads/click_lx.ads/mhoemail/jcr_dd_1113/102920131102/x19/crain/MHO_EZ_JOINTCOMM_DD_728_1113/Savelivessavemoney-Ad_ModernHealthcare_10-11-2013-2.jpg/1" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://oascentral.modernhealthcare.com/RealMedia/ads/adstream_nx.ads/mhoemail/jcr
_dd_1113/102920131102@x19" border="0"/>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1x1/"/>
    </a>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
img {width:100%;height:auto;}
td[class="ad-728"] img:nth-child(n+2) {width:1px!important;max-width:1px!important;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nth child and other CSS pseudo classes are [limited in support](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) in html email. Your best bet is to create a tiny table and put the tracking link/image in there. 100% of 1 pixel is 1 pixel...

If you don't have the ability to choose where the tracking code is placed (added dynamically on send for example), you'll have to rethink your auto 100% strategy.

Also, keep in mind that declaring 100% in the style tag is not fully supported either - you should be inlining your CSS.